# XNA adding colors when overlap

Tags: colors, xna, collision

I have sprites that when they overlap I would like them to 'add' their colors rgb values to (potentially) go white, the sprites also have changin alpha values which should remain unchanged. I've already tried using all the spritebatch options alphablend, additive etc...

Is this possible through spritebatch or will i need a shader?

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: Additive didn't give  you the desired effect?

Comment: No it didn't additive just appears to add the colors together - so green on green makes stronger green tone - by combining alphas, rahter than combining colors.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Premultiplied Alpha scheme in XNA 4, you can do additive blending by having your texture drawn at 0 alpha. Because this means that there is 0 blocking done by the texture, and then the RGB is added to the pixels behind it, you get additive blending.

Just draw the texture with 0 alpha using the spritebatch mode 'Alphablend'. To lower the additivity, increase alpha. To make it less visible, lower RGB.

I highly suggest making sure any textures in your content have the option 'Premultiplied Alpha' ticked in their properties, if you use this.

Comment: Thanks though I'm not looking for additive in seperate channels - RGB, so as in the eg above green on green produces stronger green tone but what I'm looking for is for it to go white when colors overlap either the same color or other ones.

Comment: That is exactly what this does, if you do it right. If you have only green, adding more green gives you... brighter green. Throw a little red/blue in there and you'll get your result.

Comment: I know it does that but that's not what I'm after - I looking for green on green (i.e. same color as well as alternate) to produce white.

I'll look into hlsl as an option.

Comment: Well if you're looking for that sort of thing, you might want to write a shader that uses HSV (Hue, Sat, Value). Add the values of each pixel together, average the hue and sat, and you have your effect.